# can html5 read msgs on a mobile device through a mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser, one-time-password

can html5 read msgs on a mobile device through a mobile browser??

I want to create the AUTO OTP feature for mobile browsers. It is easily achievable via mobile apps but i guess nobody has done it for mobile browsers. For example I want to provide the auto OTP via Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: (Psst... HTML 5 cannot "read" anything)

Comment: OTP? On the phone? One Term President? One Trick pony? One True Pairing? One Time Password? One Time Pad? Offer To Purchase? One Time Payment? - it's not clear from your question what you are talking about